# Use a selected value of dropdown in SelectCommand for SqlDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I would like to use a selected value of a dropdown list in a SqlDataSource SelectCommand.

```
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSelectRole" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Client</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Programming</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>Guest</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
```

**Currently:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsourceProgEmails" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT  [Email] + ',' AS [text()] FROM [SiteUsers] WHERE [Role] = 'Programming' FOR XML PATH ('')">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**I'm thinking something like:**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsourceProgEmails" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT  [Email] + ',' AS [text()] FROM [SiteUsers] WHERE [Role] = '" + ddlSelectRole.SelectedValue + "' FOR XML PATH ('')">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Code-behind is C#.

Comment: Did you try autopostback="true"?

Comment: Write your query with passing parameter using @Role and then try this inside selectparameters tag: <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlSelectRole" DefaultValue="0" Name="Role" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your query should look like this in your SqlDataSource:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [Email] + ',' AS [text] FROM [SiteUsers] WHERE [Role] = @RoleID FOR "
```

Then specify where to get the value for RoleID here

```
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:ControlParameter Name="RoleID" ControlID="ddlSelectRole" 
        PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
```

- [ControlParameter Class - Used with SqlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter.aspx)
- [ControlParameter example: how to use ControlParameter](http://asp-net-example.blogspot.com/2008/11/aspnet-controlparameter-example-how-to.html)

Comment: Hi @codingbiz, I'm getting the error 'Could not find control 'ddlSelectRole' in ControlParameter 'RoleID'.' This is because the dropdown list is in an <InsertItemTemplate> of a FormView. How to fix this?

Comment: @kyle_13 the control you put in the InsertTemplate will only be visible at runtime and not in design mode. So, SqlDataSource would not be able to locate the control on the page. You should move the SqlDataSource also into the InsertTemplate.

Comment: Hi @codingbiz, it's not letting me go further because I reference that datasource in another spot in the code-behind, in the onInserted event of a record, which sends a confirmation email out:     `DataView dvProgEmails = (DataView)dsourceProgEmails.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    string emailsTo = (string)dvProgEmails.Table.Rows[0][0];
    emailsTo = emailsTo.TrimEnd(',');` Gives me the error: _Error - The name 'dsourceProgEmails' does not exist in the current context_

Comment: Hi @codingbiz, never mind, I figured it out, all I had to do was use FindControl after moving the datasource. `SqlDataSource dsourceToEmails = (SqlDataSource)formViewNewItem.FindControl("dsourceToEmails");` Thanks so much, all is good now!

Comment: Cool you figured that out. I should have mentioned that in my comment.